# Exception handling at the top layer

Tags: java, exception

Of course exceptions should be handled at the appropriate level you think and appropriately. Suppose you don't know what to do with checked exception and you wrap it in appropriate custom unchecked exception just to propagate up to the top level (it is supposed that you don't handle that wrapped exception and other possible unchecked exceptions at some medium level up apart the level which original exception occurred at (because of you don't want or don't know how)). Go further, All unhandled exceptions (unchecked and checked, that were wrapped in unchecked) reached the top level (main method, controller of webapp, etc); of course I should something to do. All I want to do is to notify the developer by using log entry that something was wrong and communicate the user that his request can't be serviced correctly (using different messages in dependence of what message is appropriate for that exception). To do that, I use in catch block `RuntimeException` (if it catches not custom unchecked exception, I’ll send the user a message "Serious problem occurred" or something like that; probability that such not custom unchecked exception will be cached greater than zero, and you must communicate about it). Some articles ([first](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html?page=1), [second](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/04/java-exception-handling-best-practices/)) advise not to catch instances of subclasses by super type in catch block (or it is only related to checked exceptions?). If I used accurate types of exceptions in catch blocks I would miss some unchecked exceptions and application would crash (and of course there would be duplicate code snippets in those catch blocks performing logging and notifying the user). As an example, I can provide the snippet that is constructed in jsp translation phase and uses super type to catch instances of subclasses of that supertype

```
// some code
try {
    // body of translated JSP here...
} catch (Exception e) {
    out.clear();
    pageContext.handlePageException(e);
}
// some code
```

My question: **is this concept is correct to use `RuntimeException` in catch block at the top level to report about all problems to developer and communicate the user about all occurred problems?** Of course, exception handling in this case is reduced to just notifying developer and user that the problems occurred and there are no recovering strategies. Maybe it is hard to call that concept as exception handling. Please correct me and I appreciate any ideas about that concept.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrapping all your `Exception`s with a `RuntimeException`, and handling them in your `main` method, or wherever you define as being your top level, is a very bad practice. Instances of `Exception` should be handled as close as possible from where they were thrown, as they exist to identify an error from which you can recover. For instance, if you are trying to open a file, and get a `FileNotFoundException`, you should then take action on this (display an error message, add an entry in your error log, etc.).

Most of the time, `RuntimeException` represent programming errors (). More often than not, they indicate that the application is in an unstable state, and recovery is hard if not impossible. `IllegalStateException`, `NullPointerException` and `IndexOutOfBoundsException` are examples of such situations.

Now, the concept you are proposing, where all `RuntimeException`s are caught in the top-level method is not a viable solution for any software containing more than a few hundred lines of code, and a very bad practice in shorter programs.

Assume you have an application with 100k lines of code. Once an exception has been thrown, it will be impossible from your top-level method to correctly handle your exception. What should it do if it is a `NullPointerException`? Where was it thrown from? And what about that `CloneNotSupportedException`? You will end up having a top-level method dozens of pages long that will handle every possible exception, with the biggest `if-then-else` statement of all time.

Additionally, if you implement such a concept, you should be aware that whenever an exception is thrown, your application will go in that `catch` block in your top-level method. Once you have logged the error, you will never be able to return the control to the part of your application that generated the error, because you will not have the context from which the `Exception` was thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You suggest don't postpone handling checked exceptions to the top level(do it as soon as possible(send a message, create a log entry, etc)), I agree. But how I should be in situations where it is occurred unexpected unchecked exceptions you mentioned(NullPointerException, etc)? I agree these unchecked exceptions because of my coding and recovering isn't possible;but if I don't catch these exceptions at the top level, the application will crash and this situation worse than if I catch these exceptions and provide a message

Comment: You can implement your own [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html), and make it so that you log the exception trace, display an error message to the user, then close the application.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and efforts

Comment: No probs. You should upvote the answer(s) that helped you, if any did, and you should mark as accepted the answer that helped you the most, if any did fix your problem. This is the way to thank people on SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your situation this is the right way to go.

You don't want users at best to be confused by seeing a stack trace and at worst revealing possible security issues by seeing back-end server names, database credentials, database schema etc.

Your catch should hide this information from users and print a helpful error message to the user instead so at least they know what the problem is.

My only concern with your code is perhaps you should catch `RuntimeException` separately from `Exception` (or even `Throwable`)

```
try {
    // body of translated JSP here...
}catch(RuntimeException re){
    //something unexpected
    //handle here
} catch (Exception e) {
   //checked exception
   //handle here
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Reading many articles that claims "you shouldn't catch instances of subclasses by superclass type in catch block" confused me.

Comment: Usually you shouldn't, but in the `main()` or top level sometimes it's appropriate to avoid showing the user to much information.